# Create category on runtime/dynamically in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic-programming, objective-c-category

I have a class BaseObject in my project, now I want to create category at runtime and add methods to them also at runtime.

Actually it's a framework project and I need to access one of the Class of Main project from Library project without any duplication. My main project has that BaseObject class and I need to execute some code of that class in my framework project.

I though category might be solution.

Please let me know how can I do that. I will try to give more information if required.

Thanks in advance.